# TezosOperationError: (permanent) proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.bad_stack

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I am getting following issues:

compilation warning: [warning] Error in generated Michelson contract: previous error

deployment error: "TezosOperationError: (permanent) proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.bad_stack
" issue while deploying a contract. I am using for loop in the elements of a set in a function as below:

```
self.data.link_names = self.data.link_names.add('btp://77.tezos/tz1e2HPzZWBsuExFSM4XDBtQiFnaUB5hiPnW')
sp.for item in self.data.link_names.elements():
    sp.trace("hello")
```

In the above case if i use "if " instead of for it doesn’t give this error.

```
sp.if sp.len(self.data.list_link_names.elements()> 0:
    sp.trace("hello")
```

Comment: Please share the minimal code with a scenario that produces this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was from  `sp.failwith("Empty list") and sp.failwith("Only one element")` in the below function. When I commented out those lines it worked. I is a issue with sp.failwith() which i requested smartpy dev Jordan to investigate further.

```
def split_btp_address(self, base):
        """
        Split the BTP Address format i.e. btp://1234.iconee/0x123456789
        into Network_address (1234.iconee) and Server_address (0x123456789)
        :param base: String base BTP Address format to be split
        :return: The resulting strings of Network_address and Server_address
        """
        sp.set_type(base, sp.TString)
    
        # sep = sp.local("sep", "/")
        prev_idx = sp.local("prev_idx", 0)
        result = sp.local("result", [])
        sp.for idx in sp.range(0, sp.len(base)):
            sp.if sp.slice(base, idx, 1).open_some() == "/":
                result.value.push(sp.slice(base, prev_idx.value, sp.as_nat(idx - prev_idx.value)).open_some())
                prev_idx.value = idx + 1
        sp.if sp.len(base) > 0:
            result.value.push(sp.slice(base, prev_idx.value, sp.as_nat(sp.len(base) - prev_idx.value)).open_some())
    
        inverted_list = sp.local("my_list", result.value)
        last = sp.local("last", "")
        penultimate = sp.local("penultimate", "")
    
        with sp.match_cons(inverted_list.value) as l:
            last.value = l.head
            inverted_list.value = l.tail
        # with sp.else_():
        #     sp.failwith("Empty list")
    
    
        with sp.match_cons(inverted_list.value) as l:
            penultimate.value = l.head
        # with sp.else_():
        #     sp.failwith("Only one element")
    
        return sp.pair(last.value, penultimate.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue might be the way you are adding elements to the set.

Instead of

```
self.data.link_names = self.data.link_names.add('btp://77.tezos/tz1e2HPzZWBsuExFSM4XDBtQiFnaUB5hiPnW')
```

Use

```
self.data.link_names.add("https://tezos.com")
```

This will solve the issue

Comment: Actually this alos didn't solve the issue, the issue is from lthe line sp.for. I if remove for statement it works.

Comment: @theBatMan

I am assuming that `link_names` is of set data type.
According to that you won't be able to iterate through set elements.
I'll suggest you to use list.